# No entiendo por qué me imprime dos veces el mensaje de salida

Tags: c, while

En el siguiente código (en C), luego de ingresar el dato, me larga 2 veces seguidas el primer mensaje y quisiera que fuera sólo 1 vez por "turno", además que alguien me explique por qué pasa (cómo va el flujo). Gracias.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    char caracter;
    
    while (caracter !=' '){
        printf("Ingrese un caracter: ");
        caracter=getchar();
        switch (caracter){
        case 'A':
            printf("El valor numerico de A es: %c", caracter );
            break;
        case 'B':
            printf("El valor numerico de B es: %c", caracter);
            break;
        case 'C':
            printf("El valor numerico de C es: %c", caracter);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getchar()` devuelve el primer caracter que encuentre en el buffer y lo remueve del mismo. Pero puede que hayan otros caracteres, como por ejemplo el salto de línea (presionaste ENTER para introducir el caracter), por eso en la siguiente vuelta aparecerá el mensaje "`Ingrese un caracter`" y siguiente `character = getchar()` tomará el valor de `'\n'`. 
Como el caracter `'\n'` no cumple con ninguna condición en el `switch - case`, no aparecerá mensaje de salida aquí, si no que en la siguiente vuelta, entonces vuelve a imprimir "`Ingrese un caracter:` " y ahora sí pregunta por un nuevo valor.

Puedes comprobarlo escribiendo, por ejemplo: `hola`. Imprimirá 5 veces `Ingrese un caracter`

Una solución sencilla sería agregar un bucle que recorra el buffer hasta llegar al final:

```
caracter = getchar();
while(getchar() != '\n');
/* resto del código */
```

---

**[!]** Por otro lado la función principal debe ser `int main()` ya que retorna un entero al final.

Answer (score 1):

el tema está en que cuando pulsas el carácter y das a enter, la aplicación procesa primero el caracter y luego vuelve y procesa la pulsación de enter.
Una solución es alterar la forma en la que capturamos las pulsaciones de tecla. El siguiente código muestra cómo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    char caracter;

    /* hacemos que todas las pulsaciones de tecla vayan 
       directamente a stdin */
    system ("/bin/stty raw");

    while (caracter != ' ')
    {
        printf("\nIngrese un caracter: ");
        caracter=getchar();
 
        switch (caracter)
        {
            case 'A':
               printf("\nEl valor numerico de A es: %c", caracter );
               break;
            case 'B':
               printf("\nEl valor numerico de B es: %c", caracter);
               break;
            case 'C':
               printf("\nEl valor numerico de C es: %c", caracter);
               break;
        }
   };

   /* Restablecemos el comportamiento al pulsar una tecla que habíamos 
      cambiado previamente */
   system ("/bin/stty cooked");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Que tal, probé el código tal cual está y no funciona...gracias igual

Comment: Me vas a perdonar, cuando lo probé no me dí cuenta que tenía marcado el compilador C++; y lo tuyo era referido a C. Perdón.